# How to make multiple search filters work with a for loop in Vue Bootstrap?

Tags: vue.js, bootstrap-vue

I have a table with some filters in each column but when I type anything all the items disappear. The console does not return any error.

Here’s the code:

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <b-table
      id="the-table"
      :per-page="perPage"
      :current-page="currentPage"
      :items="filteredItems"
      :fields="fields"
    >
      <template slot="top-row" slot-scope="{ fields }">
        <td v-for="field in fields" :key="field.key">
          <input v-model="filters[field.key]" :placeholder="field.label" />
        </td>
      </template>
    </b-table>
    <b-pagination v-model="currentPage" :total-rows="rows" :per-page="perPage" aria-controls="the-table"></b-pagination>
  </div>
</template>
```

```js
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  data() {
    return {
      filters: {
        option: "",
        style: "",
        stock: "",
      },
      items: [],
      fields: [
        { key: "options", label: "Options", sortable: true },
        { key: "style", label: "Style", sortable: true },
        { key: "stock", label: "Stock", sortable: true },
        { key: "type", label: "Type", sortable: true },
        { key: "class", label: "Class.", sortable: true },
      ],
      perPage: 15,
      currentPage: 1,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.getTable();
  },
  methods: {
    getTable() {
      axios
        .get("./data/options.json")
        .then((res) => (this.items = res.data))
        .catch((error) => console.log(error));
    },
  },
  computed: {
    rows() {
      return this.items.length;
    },
    filteredItems() {
      return this.items.filter((d) => {
        return Object.keys(this.filters).every((f) => {
          return this.filters[f].length < 1 || this.filters[f].includes(d[f]);
        });
      });
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

I am trying to filter an array of objects like this:

```json
[{"option": "ABEVH160", "style": "American", "stock": "ABEV3", "type": "CALL", "class": "ITM"},
{"option": "BBAS230", "style": "European", "stock": "BBAS3", "type": "PUT", "class": "ATM"},
{"option": "BBDC180", "style": "American", "stock": "BBDC4", "type": "CALL", "class": "OTM"}]
```

My goal is to be able to filter each of the columns individually:
[image: data-table]

Does anyone know what I’m missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is with the condition:

```js
return this.filters[f].length < 1 || this.filters[f].includes(d[f]);
```

`d[f]` is the full value and `this.filters[f]` is the search string. Obviously this does not work since it checks if the full word is contained in a substring. Simply invert the condition:

```js
return this.filters[f].length < 1 || d[f].includes(this.filters[f]);
```

You can see it working [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-cartwright-t91x3?file=/App.vue:1861-1929).

Comment: Really, I didn't pay attention and it went unnoticed. Thank you very much!!

Answer (score 2):

What you want seems to be something like [DataTable Filter | Filter Row](https://primefaces.org/primevue/showcase/#/datatable/filter) in `PrimeVue`. I tried to find something similar in the documentation of `bootstrap-vue` ([documentation)](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/table), but couldn´t find anything like that.

Maybe you are in a stage where you can still implement `PrimeVue` in your project. I´m using `Filter Row` from `PrimeVue` by myself and can recommend it.